# Proving this inequality without calculus

Tags: calculus

> For all $x\in(0,1)$, prove that $\ln x<x$.

**My attempt:**

First step:
Assume a function $f(x)=\ln x-x$. Analyzing tells me the function is continuous and non-differentiable at $x=0$.

Second step:
$F'(x) =\frac{1}{x}-1=\frac{1-x}{x}.$

This gives me $x=1$ as an extremum. From further analysis, this appears to be a global maximum.

So combining all the info, $x=1$ is the global maximum with the function decreasing at points less than it. That would mean $f(x)$ is decreasing from $(0,1]$ and $(0,1)$. Hence, this proves the inequality.

However, is there a quick non-calculus way to solve this? I thought of using Taylor series but it's not working.

Comment: Why did you change the original problem. That’s one is trivial. You should rollback to the first one and in case create a new OP for that.

Comment: which definition of logarithm do you use?

Comment: The fundamental inequality satisfied by logarithm is $\log x\leq x-1,\forall x>0$ and equality occurs only at $x=1$. Moreover this is an immediate consequence of any chosen definition of $\log x$.

Comment: 1) Please avoid chamaleon questions. 2) How is $\log$ *defined* without Calculus?

Answer (score 19):

For $x\in (0,1)$, $\log x$ is negative (because $e^t\geq 1$ for $t\geq 0$) and so $\log x<0<x$ follows.  (log is base $e$, as always).

Answer (score 6):

**Answer to the original problem**

> For all $x\in(0, 1)$ prove that $\ln(1+x) < x$ without calculus

We have

$$\ln (1+x)<x\iff 1+x<e^x$$

and by $x=\frac1y$ with $y>1$

$$1+x<e^x\iff 1+\frac1y<e^{1/y}\iff \left(1+\frac1y\right)^y<e$$

which is true. Refer to that [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Number:_Limit_of_Sequence_implies_Limit_of_Series).

Comment: Why does the last inquality hold?  It fails for $x=\frac12$, for example.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes you are right, Bernoulli indeed does not suffice! I’ve fixed that. Thanks to have pointed that out.

Comment: We can also prove $1 + x < e^x$ by using the Taylor series $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \dotsb$, and observing that all terms past $1+x$ are positive.

Comment: In the original problem it was requested without calculus.